# Dynamic Google Sheets Column + Row formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, average

I have a good sheet that I want to grab the header which a date time stamp which will match against another sheet find the entries with that date and suburb and type and give me an average cost.

My formula is =AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A, B11:B, Sheet1!F:F, C10) which gives me the average but i've hard coded the header date:

example:
[image]

What I want to do is dynamically add the data from the row above with the date time instead of of manually adding it in the formula something like this:

=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A, B11:B, Sheet1!F:F, =CHAR(COLUMN()+64) & 10)

Which would automatically grab the column + row 10 e.g C10, D10, E10.

If i put =CHAR(COLUMN()+64) & 10 in its own cell it works but when I add it to averageifs condition it gives me a parsing error.

Expecting C10, D10, E10 from =CHAR(COLUMN()+64) & 10 which should allow me to dynamically filter data on the date int he header above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!C:C, Sheet1!A:A, B11:B, Sheet1!F:F, INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&10))
```

Comment: This was the answer:

`=AVERAGEIFS('Raw Data'!C:C,'Raw Data'!A:A, A:A, 'Raw Data'!E:E,"House", 'Raw Data'!F:F, INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&2)`


Thank you!